# update cell and paste it to another cell vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new in excel vba and I would really appreciate if you can assist me.
The thing is that I have cell which updates each minute because it is linked with a function to Blomberg. The thing is that I want that each time cell updates excel copies it and pastes to another, new cell that i can observe the intra day changes. 
I have come up with some codes but I can copy and paste only to one, similar cell.It looks like following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then
Range("E4").Copy
Range("E4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to have understood well, but if you want (say) the value of `E4` being equal to the value of `D4`, why you don't simply write `=E4` in the cell `D4`?

Comment: He wants a log of changes.

Comment: P.s. anyway, among the various problems, you're copying the cell `E4` and pasting it into the cell `E4`. Is it really what you want to do? Also, consider that this would generate an infinite loop (the value of `E4` would be constantly overwritten and constantly calling the `Change` procedure).

Comment: NOt really i am sorry. it should paste it to anotther sheet range E4

Comment: @user3618375 I've posted an answer, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? It will transfer E4 to Sheet2 in a new row each time E4 changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address = "$E$4" Then Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Target

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to copy the value to a new cell, for logging purposes? What I would do in this case is have another sheet for logging the values named "logger_sheet" I paste a value in cell **a1** when the blomberg cell updates, copy the value into my **logger_sheet** cell **a2** when it changes copy it to a3 then a4 etc.

Here is your updated code. It assumes you have a sheet named "logger_sheet" (if you dont have one, create it) to store all the previous values. When the blomberg cell updates, it copies the value and pastes it to the next avaliable logging_sheet cell. I have developed a function that finds the last used row in a specified sheet and column. Try it out

Also there is a line you can uncomment if you want to prevent excel from flashing, I labeled it in the code

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    target_cell = "E4"
    col_to_log_data = "A"
    logging_Sheet = "logger_sheet"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then
        'uncomment this line to stop the "flashing"
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'gets the name of the current sheet
        data_sheet = Range(target_cell).Parent.Name
        Range(target_cell).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'gets the next free row from column a of the logging sheet (the next free row is
        'the last used row + 1)
        next_free_row = GetLastRowByColumn(CStr(col_to_log_data), CStr(logging_Sheet)) + 1

        'pastes the value
        Sheets(logging_Sheet).Range(col_to_log_data & CStr(next_free_row)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'switches back to the data sheet
        Sheets(data_sheet).Select

        'make sure you turn screen updating on (if it was never off it still works)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'this finds the last row in a specific column
'PARAMS: col_to_check, the clumn we want the last row of
'        Opt: sheet_name, the sheet you want to check last row of
'             default is current sheet if not specified
'RETURN: the last row number used in the sheet
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetLastRowByColumn(col_to_check As String, Optional sheet_name As String)

    'gets current sheet name
    the_current_sheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    'if the user didnt' specify a sheet use the current one
    If (Len(sheet_name) = 0) Then
        sheet_name = the_current_sheet
    End If

    'gets last row
    GetLastRowByColumn = Sheets(sheet_name).Range(col_to_check & "65536").End(xlUp).Row

    'returns to original sheet
     Sheets(the_current_sheet).Select
End Function
```

If my answer solves your problem please mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption you  want to log every change of values.
I would advise to keep a log in a separate sheet. Let's call it `LogSheet`.

```
Sub  WriteLog(ByRef r As range)
Dim Lastrow as integer
With ThisWorkBook.WorkSheets("LogSheet")
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(XlUp).Row
.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = Now & " - " & r.Value
End With
End Sub
```

This sub will basically write all changes in column A of our log sheet with a timestamp!

Now, we need to make changes to your code in order to tell, to make logs whenever there is a change. To do so, we're going to make a call to our function and tell to copy the content of the range("E4") (The one that gets updated all the time)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then
'add this line
WriteLog(ActiveSheet.Range("E4"))
```

Try it now.